# Embedding of Algebraic extension

Tags: galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be an algebraic field extension, show that any embedding $L\to L$ such that  $L|_K= Id_K$
is an automorphism of L. Is it true if the extension is not algebraic?

For finite case the answer is trivial. How do i prove for infinite case.

Comment: The claim does not hold when $L$ is not algebraic over $K$. For example, if $L=K(x)$ with $x$ a variable, i.e. a transcendental element, then $x\mapsto x^2$ extends uniquely to an embedding $L\to L$. Basically by the recipe $f(x)/g(x)\mapsto f(x^2)/g(x^2)$. This embedding is not surjective, because only even rational functions are in the image.

Comment: what are even rational functions

Comment: Those with the property $q(-x)=q(x)$. I realize that  in characteristic two all rational functions are "even" according to that definition :-). It would be better and simpler to just state that the element $x$ itself is not in the image of that embedding.

Comment: And, if you want number fields instead of rational functions then  you can use the following (it's the same thing, really). Both $\pi$ and $\pi^2$ are transcendental over $\Bbb{Q}$. Therefore $\pi\mapsto\pi^2$ extends to a $\Bbb{Q}$-linear isomorphism from $L=\Bbb{Q}(\pi)$ to $L'=\Bbb{Q}(\pi^2)$. Here clearly
$L'\subseteq L$, but $\pi\notin L'$ so $L'$ is a proper subset of $L$.

Answer (score 3):

Call this embedding $f$. Let $\alpha \in L$. We want to show $\alpha$ is reached by $f$. $\alpha$ has some minimal polynomial $p$ over $K$. Let $\{\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k\}$ be the (mutually distinct, i.e. $\alpha_i=\alpha_j$ iff $i=j$) roots of $p$ that lie in $L$.Then $\{f(\alpha_1),...,f(\alpha_k) \}$ are also roots of p, by the property that $f|_K=\text{id}$. Since $f$ is injective, the $f(\alpha_1),...,f(\alpha_k)$ are $k$ distinct elements of $L$, so it follows these are exactly all roots of $p$. So there must be some $i$ such that $f(\alpha_i)=\alpha$, and this finishes the proof.

NOTE: Just for (over)completeness, I'd like to add the proof in the case $L/K$ is a finite extension (maybe your proof of this fact differs!). Note that $f$ is a $K$-linear map from $L$ to $L$. Since $f$ is injective, $\text{Im} f$ is a vector subspace of $L$ of dimension $[L:K]$, so it must be the whole space, hence $f$ is surjective.